# Why choice 2 in my program crashes due to the variable?

Tags: python

i dont know the error, i've been programming in python for a total of 2 hours (also pasted code)

on vscode it gives error on line 99 and 86 and says the variable isnt dif, pls help, option 1 works fine an

i changed sme stuff of the already working cde because since its pasted from morse code thingy it gives a spacebar, choice 1 works fine, but 2 crashes

```
# Define the Morse code dictionary.
morse_dict = { 'A': 'H',
            'B': 'Z/V',
            'C': 'KKKK',
            'D': 'DC',
            'E': 'E',
            'F': 'EE',
            'G': 'GI',
            'H': 'AH',
            'I': 'RAR',
            'J': 'JA',
            'K': 'KKBKKC',
            'L': 'LM',
            'M': 'NM',
            'N': 'NN',
            'O': 'QOU',
            'P': 'P',
            'Q': 'QUE',
            'R': 'Q',
            'S': 'TST',
            'T': 'TT',
            'U': 'U',
            'V': 'W',
            'W': 'V',
            'X': 'Y',
            'Y': 'XX',
            'Z': 'ABC',
            '1': '1',
            '2': '2',
            '3': '3',
            '4': '4',
            '5': '5',
            '6': '6',
            '7': '7',
            '8': '8',
            '9': '9',
            ' ': ' ',
            '0': '0',

}
morse_dict2 = { 'H': 'A',
            'Z/V': 'B',
            'KKKK': 'C',
            'DC': 'D',
            'E': 'E',
            'EE': 'F',
            'GI': 'G',
            'AH': 'H',
            'RAR': 'I',
            'JA': 'J',
            'KKBKKC': 'K',
            'LM': 'L',
            'NM': 'M',
            'NN': 'N',
            'QOU': 'O',
            'P': 'P',
            'QUE': 'Q',
            'Q': 'R',
            'TST':'S',
            'TT': 'T',
            'U': 'U',
            'W': 'V',
            'V': 'W',
            'Y': 'X',
            'XX': 'Y',
            'ABC': 'Z',
            '1': '1',
            '2': '2',
            '3': '3',
            '4': '4',
            '5': '5',
            '6': '6',
            '7': '7',
            '8': '8',
            '9': '9',
            ' ': ' ',
            '0': '0',

}
# Convert a message to Morse code.
def to_morse_code(message):
    return "".join(morse_dict[char] for char in message.upper())

# Convert a Morse code sequence to a message.
def from_morse_code(morse_code2):
    return "".join(morse_dict2[char] for char in message2.upper())

# User interface
def main():
    while True:
        choice = input("Choose an option:\nPress 1 to convert text to Morse code\nPress 2 to convert Morse code to text\nPress -1 to quit\n")
        if choice == '1':
            message = input("Enter a message to convert to Morse code: ")
            morse_code = to_morse_code(message)
            print(morse_code)
        
        elif choice == '2':
            message = input("Enter a Morse code sequence to convert to text: ")
            morse_code2 = from_morse_code(morse_code2)
            print(message)
        
        elif choice == '-1':
            print("Quitted successfully")
            break
            
        else:
            print("Invalid choice, please choose from the available options.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: You wanted `from_morse_code(message)`

Comment: _on vscode it gives error on line 99 and 86 and says the variable isnt dif_ Please post the full error traceback message.  Don't make us guess what you mean by "the variable".

Comment: which line is 99 and 86?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In testing out your code, the first issue was fairly easy to spot using "a second set of eyes".  Various input variables and parameters were incorrectly being referenced when attempting to decode the input data.

```
    elif choice == '2':
        message = input("Enter a Morse code sequence to convert to text: ")
        morse_code2 = from_morse_code(morse_code2)
        print(message)
```

The function parameter should be "message" and not "morse_code2".  And the variable for the print statement would then be "morse_code2".

Once that bit was noted and corrected, the subsequent call to the "morse_code2" function was falling over as an assumption was made on searching the dictionary and replacing values.  For the encoding of an input message in function "morse_code", each character is replaced by one or more characters.  However, that same loop and search method does not work for the decoding as most encoded values are strings and not single characters.

With that following is the refactored version of the code with corrected logic for decoding an encoded message (the dictionaries were omitted as nothing was changed in them).

```
# Convert a message to Morse code.
def to_morse_code(message):
    return "".join(morse_dict[char] for char in message.upper())

# Convert a Morse code sequence to a message.
def from_morse_code(message2):
    work = ""
    text = ""
    for char in message2.upper():
        work = work + char                  # Build string until it equates to a dictionary entry
        if work in morse_dict2:
            text = text + morse_dict2[work]
            work = ""
    return text

# User interface
def main():
    while True:
        choice = input("Choose an option:\nPress 1 to convert text to Morse code\nPress 2 to convert Morse code to text\nPress -1 to quit\n")
        if choice == '1':
            message = input("Enter a message to convert to Morse code: ")
            morse_code = to_morse_code(message)
            print(morse_code)
        
        elif choice == '2':
            message = input("Enter a Morse code sequence to convert to text: ")
            morse_code2 = from_morse_code(message)  # Correct the input parameter
            print(morse_code2)                      # Correct the print parameter
            
        elif choice == '-1':
            print("Quitted successfully")
            break
            
        else:
            print("Invalid choice, please choose from the available options.")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Following are the key points.

- in the "main" function, the correction is made to the usage of the "message" and "morse_code2" variables so that the function call will work.
- in function "morse_code2", a test is made to see if a character or group of characters are in the dictionary, and when found then use the dictionary value for the character/string to build a decoded message.

With that, following is a test at the terminal for the refactored code.

```
craig@Vera:~/Python_Programs/Morse$ python3 Morse.py 
Choose an option:
Press 1 to convert text to Morse code
Press 2 to convert Morse code to text
Press -1 to quit
1
Enter a message to convert to Morse code: duh
DCUAH
Choose an option:
Press 1 to convert text to Morse code
Press 2 to convert Morse code to text
Press -1 to quit
2
Enter a Morse code sequence to convert to text: dcuah
DUH
Choose an option:
Press 1 to convert text to Morse code
Press 2 to convert Morse code to text
Press -1 to quit
-1
Quitted successfully
```

The key things to take away is ensure that in function calls, the correct parameter has been entered, be careful of cloning functionality from one function to another function, and possibly delve more into some python tutorials as it pertains to the usage of dictionaries.

Comment: thanks for helping, we all start somewhere